# Can i display multiple views of the same file with CRichEditCtrl?

Tags: winapi, mfc, richedit

I have to CRichEditCtrl controls in a dialog window with multiple tabs which might display the same file.

How can i synchronize the editing in them?

Comment: Normal/expected behaviour is to prompt if it's changed when you switch to/activate the tab/window/edit box. This allows someone to keep an "unchanged" or scratch copy in one window while editign the other. If they're for a split edit feature (i.e. Visual Studio's split editor) then what you ask is fine, but I don't knwo how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `CPropertySheet` and `CPropertyPage` for multiple-tab support, you may override `CPropertyPage::OnSetActive` and `CPropertyPage::OnKillActive`. Set the current text in `OnKillActive` and set the same text for other tab that is going to be active (in `OnSetActive`).

Comment: Sorry doesn't work because in one case they can be even on the same page.